# NSMutableSet of buttons error 'NSMutableSet' is not a supported collection class. Expected subclass of NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I thought this was pretty straight forward but I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong.
I'm trying to give multiple buttons a border though I keep on getting an error:

> 'NSMutableSet' is not a supported collection class. Expected subclass
>   of NSArray.

Here is my code in the .h file:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSMutableSet* btn;
```

I've linked this to the buttons on my XIB.

In my .m file I placed this in the viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    for (UIButton *b in self.btn) {

        b.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
        b.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    }

}
```

Thank you if you can help.

Comment: AFAIK `IBOutletCollection` can only be used with `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`. Did you try changing `btw` accordingly?

Comment: I tried changing to NSArray and NsMutableArray though the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out but is there a neater way to write the code in the .m file?

Here's the .h file code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *btn;
```

In the .m file I did this:

```
for (int i=0; i < [self.btn count]; i++)
{
    [[[self.btn objectAtIndex:i]layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];

    [[[self.btn objectAtIndex:i]layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor ];        
}
```

}

But there are so many brackets:
Is there a simpler way to write this below? :

```
    [[[self.btn objectAtIndex:i]layer] 
     setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor ];
```

Comment: `self.btn[i].borderColor=UIColor.blackColor.CGColor;`

Comment: @GerdK, you lost the `layer` property access. Gerard, since you're doing two things to the layer, you may wish to create a local for it to simply the code: `CALayer* layer = self.btn[i].layer; layer.borderWidth = 1; layer.borderColor = ...;`

Comment: Or use fast enumeration (sorry, formatting gets lost in comments):

 `for(UIButton *button in btn)
 {
  button.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
  button.layer.borderColor=UIColor.blackColor.CGColor;
 }`